# Local variable 'basename' can't be referenced before it is declared / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having an issue with base name as I look to official documentation of **basename** and everything seems to me "ok". But it still shows errors on **basename**. Thank you for your time!

**Errors**
Error with basename: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked
Local variable 'basename' can't be referenced before it is declared.

**Code Snippet**

```
 Future uploadImageToFirebase(BuildContext context) async {

    String basename = basename(_imageFile.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$basename');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
          (value) => print("Done: $value"),
        );
  }
```

**context part code snippet**

```
  void addToFb() async {
    final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    ...

    dbRef.add({
    ...
    }).then((res) {
      isLoading = false;

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,             <--- HERE I GOT AND ERROR
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(uid: widget.uid)),
      );
    }).catchError(
  (err) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,      <--- HERE I GOT AND ERROR
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Error"),
          content: Text(err.message),
          actions: [
          ...
          ],
        );
      },
...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String basename = basename(_imageFile.path);`

You're using the same name. Change the variable's name to something else, e.g. `String _basename = basename(_imageFile.path);`

What you're doing is basically "Set a value to variable 'basename' by calling 'basename' function". Can you see the name clash?

Comment: Thanks, but at first i have used String fileName instead of basename and i have left it with that one

Comment: Now i do get 'The method 'basename' isn't defined for the type '_UploadingImageToFirebaseStorageState'.' error and as i said it seems to be declared "ok" to me, i don't know

Comment: Well, I guess the 'basename' should be this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-path_path/basename.html . Did you import the library? It's hard to tell without the entire code. It would help if you provide a complete example somewhere

Comment: Yes i have, import 'package:path/path.dart as path' , but i found out now if i delete 'path' then i do get error on 'context' Error:The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type

Comment: In that case, since you imported it "as path", you should have written `path.basename(...)`. Please provide an example as complete as possible, maybe interactive too; we could go on for days trying to fix every other error, it's not feasible this way

Comment: Gazie @Giovanni, it works! All it needed path.basename(...) sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score -2):

if dart constructor  not create , you get some error message:

```
Local variable 'x' can't be referenced before it is declared / Flutter
```